# Optimization problem with input variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I've been trying to solve an optimization problem using Mathematica. I'm 100% familiar with the programme, I just practised a few tutorials available online, but they were very small and the problem is a bit larger.
This is a screenshot of the actual problem
[image]

This is my attempt at using Mathematica to solve the problem.
[image]

I also copied the script from the screenshot above. The script is as follows:

```
NMaximize[{(1/T) (p (Q - E) + 10 x - 20 Q - 10 - 
 5 ((6000) 25^0.6 e^(-0.1 p) + (Subscript[t, 1]^3/(6 (0.04)) - 
      Subscript[t, 1]^2/2) + Subscript[Qt, 1]) - (5/2) (25 + 
    E) (T - Subscript[t, 1])), 
  Q == 25 + (((6000) 25^0.6 e^(-0.1 p))/(2 (0.04))) (0.04^2 - (0.04 - 
       T)^2 - (2 (0.04) (25^(1 - 0.6) - E^(1 - 0.6)))/(6000 (1 - 
          0.6) e^(-0.1 p))) && Q >= w && Subscript[t, 1] = 
   0.04 - Sqrt[(0.04 - 
     T)^2 - (2 (0.04) (25^(1 - 0.6) - E^(1 - 0.6)))/(6000 (1 - 
        0.6) e^(-0.1 p))] && Subscript[t, 1] >= 0 && E >= 0 && 
    w >= E && Subscript[t, 1] >= 0 && T >= Subscript[t, 1] && 
    m >= T}, {E, p, T, Q, Subscript[t, 1]}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. `E` represents the base of natural log. In general use lower case letters for user-defined symbols. Please update the post with this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to correcting the equations, also include the constraint that `p > 0`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

(sys = {(1/t) (p (q - e) + s*e - c*q - o - 
       h (α*w^β*E^(-λ*p) (t1^3/(6 m) - t1^2/2) + 
          q*t1) - (h/2) (w + e) (t - t1)), 
    q == w + ((α w^β E^(-λ*p))/(2 m))*(m^2 - (m - 
            t)^2 - (2 m (w^(1 - β) - 
              e^(1 - β)))/(α (1 - β) E^(-λ*p))), 
    q >= w, 
    t1 == 
     m - Sqrt[(m - 
           t)^2 + (2 m (w^(1 - β) - 
             e^(1 - β)))/(α (1 - β) E^(-λ*p))], 
    t1 >= 0, e >= 0, w >= e, t >= t1, m >= t, p > 0});

α = 6000; β = 0.6; λ = 0.1; c = 20; (* $/unit *) 
h = 5; (* $/unit/year *) m = 0.04; (* years *) 
o = 10; (* $/order *) s = 10; (* $/unit *) 
w = 25; (* units *)
```

Maximizing,

```
NMaximize[sys, {e, p, t, q, t1}]

(* {8366.52, {e -> 6.51561, p -> 28.1919, t -> 0.0231873, q -> 39.6589, 
  t1 -> 0.00645804}} *)
```

Comment: Don;t you think that $e$ in the question stands for `E` in Wolfram Language (see the attached image))?

Comment: @user64494 - Yes, that is why I entered `e` as `E` and converted the variable `E` to `e`.

Comment: You should rewrite $e^{...}$ as `Exp[...]`, not as `e^... ` with a variable `e`. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @user64494 - compare my equations with the image. Where the image showed `e^x` (exponentiation) I used `E^x`; where the image showed the variable `E` raised to a power (I.e., `E^x`) I changed this to `e^x` since the variable is now `e`

Comment: @user64494 - in the image the only `Exp` terms are `e^(-λ*p)`; in my equations these are all entered as `E^(-λ*p)`. And in my equations, the image's `E^(1-β)` are entered as `e^(1-β)`. I agree with your concept but not your reading of my equations.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get around the problem, much appreciated.